# Pure virtual function implementation

Tags: c++, inheritance, definition, virtual-functions, one-definition-rule

I'm reading Scott Meyers' *Effective C++* and I'm at the section about inheritance. He said that

> Pure virtual functions specify inheritance of interface only.
>
> Simple (impure) virtual functions specify inheritance of interface
>   plus inheritance of a default implementation.

Now, consider the following two classes:

```
struct A {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

void A::foo(){ std::cout << "Default foo" << std::endl; }

struct B : A{
    virtual void foo(){ A::foo(); std::cout << "Derived foo" << std::endl; }
};
```

We still can provide a default implementation for pure virtual functions as I did in the example and  call it via `qualified-function-call-expression`. We can do almost the same for impure virtual functions

```
struct A {
    virtual void foo(); //No longer pure virtual
};

void A::foo(){ std::cout << "Default foo" << std::endl; }

struct B : A{
    virtual void foo(){ A::foo(); std::cout << "Derived foo" << std::endl; }
};
```

If I don't define the ***impure*** virtual function as follows:

```
struct A {
    virtual void foo();
};



struct B : A{
    virtual void foo(){ std::cout << "Derived foo" << std::endl; }
};
```

it'll work perfectly fine.

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5474944f7b0036a)

So, the only purpose of pure virtual functions is to make a class abstract (non-instanciatable)?

Comment: Choosing the so-called default implementation still requires the derived class to explicitly do so.

Comment: @chris Yes, but in the impure virtual function too..

Comment: @chris look at this [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5474944f7b0036a). I didn't ever define the base-class function.

Comment: Your demo [doesn't always work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a892f6e2fa8fe342) if you call `foo` through a base class reference/pointer. Compiling with gcc always results in a linker error, while with clang it depends on the optimization level.

Comment: @stella, Not in the impure virtual function, too. If a derived class wants to use the base class implementation, it can simply not provide an overriding function. That's not to say it can implicitly use the base class implementation as *part* of its own implementation, but by choosing the default implementation, I mean the entire implementation.

Comment: *"We still can provide a default implementation for pure virtual functions as I did in the example and call it via..."* - if it was the "default implementation" you wouldn't need to call it explicitly.  It's just *an* implementation - C++ conveniently lets you use the same function name so it can be a hint to developers writing derived classes that it might be a useful support function for their own implementation, but it wouldn't make any real difference if the base class couldn't implement pure virtuals and might supply a differently named support function.

Comment: Your last example causes undefined behaviour (no diagnostic required): since `A::foo()` is not marked `= 0;`, it must have a body somewhere (even if it is never called).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pure virtual function not only makes the base class non-instantiable, but **forces** all derived classes to implement the corresponding virtual function. If you don't make the base function pure virtual, then the derived classes may choose to not implement it. Defining the pure virtual function is OK, as long as you use it from a derived instance, and it provides an implementation that can be used as default, as Scott Meyers points out.

Note that your demo doesn't work as you think. If you do what usually is regarding as common when using polymorphism,

```
A* p = new B; // or, std::unique_ptr<A> p = make_unique<B>();
p->foo();
```

then you get a nasty linker error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "typeinfo for A", referenced from:
>        typeinfo for B in ccoVYpAI.o